# How to add a topographic map to a shapefile?

Tags: r, maps, topography

I wonder how it's possible to add this [topographic information](https://osm2.cartodb.com/tables/contour_1/public) (elevation) to the map of Santa Cruz Island and all of the Galápagos Island that I have here.

```
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(ggsn)
myGPS = data.frame(lat=c( -0.6850556,-0.6854722,  -0.6857778  ),lon=c(-90.22275,-90.22261,  -90.22272)) 
coord.deg = myGPS

class(coord.deg)
## "data.frame"
coordinates(coord.deg)<-~lon+lat
class(coord.deg)
## "SpatialPointsDataFrame"
## attr(,"package")
## "sp"

# does it have a projection/coordinate system assigned?
proj4string(coord.deg) # nope
## NA

# Manually tell R what the coordinate system is
proj4string(coord.deg)<-CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84")

# now we can use the spTransform function to project. We will project
# the mapdata and for coordinate reference system (CRS) we will
# assign the projection from counties

coord.deg<-spTransform(coord.deg, CRS(proj4string(gal)))
# double check that they match
identical(proj4string(coord.deg),proj4string(gal))
## [1] TRUE
my_pts <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = coord.deg, data=data.frame(id=1:length(coord.deg)))

URL <- "https://osm2.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql?filename=public.galapagos_islands&q=select+*+from+public.galapagos_islands&format=geojson&bounds=&api_key="
fil <- "gal.json"
if (!file.exists(fil)) download.file(URL, fil)
gal <- readOGR(fil, "OGRGeoJSON")
gal <- gSimplify(gUnaryUnion(spTransform(gal, CRS("+init=epsg:31983")), id=NULL), tol=0.001)
gal_map <- fortify(gal)
rand_pts <- spTransform(my_pts, CRS("+init=epsg:31983"))

# ggplot can't deal with a SpatialPointsDataFrame so we can convert back to a data.frame
my_pts <- data.frame(my_pts)
my_pts.final = my_pts[,2:3]
# we're not dealing with lat/long but with x/y
# this is not necessary but for clarity change variable names
names(my_pts.final)[names(my_pts.final)=="lat"]<-"y"
names(my_pts.final)[names(my_pts.final)=="lon"]<-"x"

gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(map=gal_map, data=gal_map,
                    aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=id),
                    color="black", fill="#FFFFFF", size=.5)
gg <- gg + coord_equal()
gg <- gg + ggsn:::scalebar(gal_map, dist=50, location="bottomleft", st.size=5)
gg <- gg + theme_map()
gg <- gg + geom_point(data=my_pts.final, aes(x=x, y=y), color="red")
gg
```

Do you have any idea? Do you have a package in R that does this?

I added this:

```
topo <- readOGR("public.geojson.json", layer ="OGRGeoJSON")
topo <- spTransform(topo, CRS("+init=epsg:31983"))
gg + geom_map(map = topo_map, data = topo_map, aes(map_id=id))
```

But it creates a map with a black shape in it... [image]

Comment: Have you tried zooming in? At this extent, anything is going to look like garbage, except for larger boundaries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your topomap is a SpatialLinesDataframe. `geom_map` is used for polygons. I suggest you use `geom_path` as below. It connects observations in original order. (`geom_line` would order by x value, which you also don't want).

```
topo <- readOGR("public.geojson.json", layer ="OGRGeoJSON") 
topo <- spTransform(topo, CRS("+init=epsg:31983"))
class(topo)
#[1] "SpatialLinesDataFrame"
topo_map <- fortify(topo)

# add the attributes back in
library(plyr)
topo_map <- join(topo_map, topo@data, by="id")

names(topo_map)
#[1] "long"       "lat"        "order"      "piece"      "group"     
#[6] "id"         "elev"       "cartodb_id" "created_at" "updated_at"

ggplot() + 
  geom_path(data = topo_map, aes(long, lat, group=group, colour=elev), size=0.1) +
  scale_colour_gradient(low="green", high="brown") +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have a way to add colours corresponding to the elevation? 
 `geom_path(data = topo_map, aes(long, lat, group=group),size=0.1,colour=elevation) `?

Comment: `fortify` removes the attributes, so you have to join them back with the dataframe. See my additions above.